# OSM Overpass: Query within relation

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

If I want to query for certain objects within an area, it's quite easy:

```
area(...);
node(area)[natural=peak];
out;
```

But what if the area is defined as a relation in the OSM database? I could query for the area like this ...

```
(rel(...);>;);
out;
```

... but how can I use the *area* filter on it then?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can either apply the same filter criteria to area, as you would for your relation - or - use `map_to_area` to calculate the corresponding area for a relation:

```
rel(...);map_to_area;
node(area)[natural=peak];
out;
```

Check out the [documentation](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Map_way.2Frelation_to_area_.28map_to_area.29) for more details.